# Finding a Relationship between 2 Numerical Variables on a Scatterplot

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear

new to stats and regressions, and finding it super interesting, however getting stuck on a subject, thanks for your responses in advance;

I have a project I am working on, where it is a multivariate linear regression model between numerical variables.

I have plotted each numerical variable against y in scatterplots and trying to transform the variables for a better fit of the model, 
but really struggling to find a relationship just by looking at the scatterplot of 2 variables as I dont know how to detect the patterns, and this is preventing me from doing good transformations for a better fit of the model.

Is there a way to master this skill ? any courses or subjects you recommend to teach me doing this ?

(for ex, the relationship from the scatterplots could be exp(1/x), or sin(x)+cos(x), or x^2 -5 or abs(x)... etc.... or more complicated ones)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not do any more complicated rescaling without having a theoretical basis on which to justify the rescaling. There are lots of different ways to rescale data. If you try them all, you are bound to find one that gives results on your training case. However if you take the function that works best on your training cases, it is very likely going to give bad results on any new cases. Google: overfitting.
If you know your data is for example exponentially distributed from the theory, a logarithm might be appropriate. Otherwise, you might normalize it (substract the mean, divide by the variance), but keep it at that.

Comment: thanks for your response. however, I am interested in learning how to find the relationship between 2 numerical variables. Are there are resources online or books you can redirect me too ? I would like to get to a stage when I look at a scatterplot, be able to say, I need to do 'This' type of transformation for the variable to better capture the scatterplot